# What does the keyword "new" mean in an interface?

Tags: typescript

I was going through the documentation of typescript and found one example

```
interface ClockConstructor {
    new (hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;
}
interface ClockInterface {
    tick();
}

function createClock(ctor: ClockConstructor, hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface {
    return new ctor(hour, minute);
}

class DigitalClock implements ClockInterface {
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
    tick() {
        console.log("beep beep");
    }
}
class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface {
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
    tick() {
        console.log("tick tock");
    }
}

let digital = createClock(DigitalClock, 12, 17);
let analog = createClock(AnalogClock, 7, 32);
```

I got all the concept of interface but i am stuck at the concept of having a **new** key word in interface with anonymous object declaration

```
 interface ClockConstructor {
        new (hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;
    }
```

I am not able to get what is the purpose behind it and how it works? I found it on https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: There's not inherently anything "anonymous" about the declaration. Can you clarify what you mean with that?

Comment: What i want to ask is, what is this line means - new (hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;

Comment: It means the function call `new Clock(0,0)` is valid, assuming `Clock` is compatible with the `ClockConstructor` interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It declares that objects of this interface are constructor functions, and callable using the `new` keyword.

Comment: How can you create object of interface - 
It declares that "objects of this interface" are constructor functions, and callable using the new keyword.

Comment: Interfaces in typescript are simply descriptions of the "shape" of objects. You do not explicitly have to mention anywhere that you are instantiating something which is compatible with an interface.

Comment: I got you point. But how is this working? Just look at first line of createClock method, this method is accepting first argument as type of "ClockConstructor", But we are passing a complete class "DigitalClock" which implements "ClockInterface" interface so certainly "DigitalClock" class is not type of "ClockConstructor". But still createClock method accepting it. I really dont know why and how?. OOPS never work like this.

Comment: No it's correct. The class keyword in TypeScript is shorthand for a constructor function with members assigned to the prototype of said function. `DigitalClock` is of type `ClockConstructor`, and _not_ compatible with `ClockInterface`: You cannot call `DigitalClock.tick()` directly, only on instances of the class. `(new DigitalClock()).tick()` is valid, however, and thus instances of `DigitalClock` are compatible with `ClockInterface`.